# cannot resolve 'findviewbyid(int)'

Tags: java, android, android-layout, findviewbyid

excuse me for repeating this question, but i saw the other answers and i just can't get it right. I'm new to android, and new to english :/

```
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.ImageView;


public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity{

    private ImageView pengesa1;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    }

    public void run(){

        pengesa1 = (ImageView) findViewByID(R.id.imageView3);
    }
}
```

here's my code, can anybody tell me what to do?

Comment: Why don't you just enable the autocomplete so you wouldn't make mistakes like that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have a typo in your method name. Change

```
findViewByID
```

to

```
findViewById
```

Comment: oh :( forgive me for the silly question. Thank you!!